# 91 Jeep YJ - Intermittent Loss of Power in Gear

Tags: troubleshooting, manual-transmission, intermittent-problems

The other morning, I pulled out of the house in first gear just fine. Switched to 2nd successfully, started accelerating as it should, then it suddenly lost engine power - no acceleration, no revving, just a dead gas pedal. Shifted back down to 1st and it goes just fine. Go back up, same thing again (I did this at least 5 times that morning).

This happened twice in a two day span last week (2nd gear for me, 4th gear for my wife), but the mechanics have had it for a week driving all over town without having it act up. Looking for some insight, since I can't trust it if I get it back untouched.

A friend of mine said it could be some kind of sensor? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site. It could be a number of things. There just isn't enough information here for us to know for sure. There will likely be some who will give you suggestions on what to check, but that is about it. Did the mechanic read the codes from the computer? Does it only happen when it is raining? More details will help.

Comment: Thanks. It happened one evening and then again the following morning, both in dry weather, normal ~70° temps. The Jeep is a 91, so no OBD computer, unfortunately. Looking for any suggestions that people may have, so I can give them to the mechanic. They say they need to see it happen before they can do much. They've mentioned returning it to me, but I need it to be reliable.

Comment: Understand your frustration.  Just don't know where to start with this. Anything we ask is likely what the mechanic has already checked. Has it been regularly serviced? Does it need a tuneup? The problem could be any number of things like water in the fuel that has worked its way out.

Comment: What RPM did this occur at? What speed were you going? Did any dashboard lights illuminate?

Comment: Does the engine completely die (as in stop running completely)? Do any of the other electrical systems stop working (dash lights, headlights, blinkers etc.)? If it's a lack of engine power then it would probably be a few basic areas to check (fuel input, ignition, air input, valve action etc.). If it's an electrical issue then I would be totally lost. I don't know of any connection between the trans and motor electrics at that age... Researching a little it does look like it has some kind of multi-port (E)FI system, so maybe check that out...

Comment: Maybe 2k RPMs or so, in the middle of 2nd gear, about 20 mph. No dashboard lights illuminated that I know of. Engine did not completely stall out, as it worked again when I downshifted to 1st gear. The mechanic drove it all around town for the last week and could not reproduce, so I got it back this morning. I'm hoping it was some kind of fluke or one-time thing like bad fuel.